# TemplateURL must reference a valid S3 object to which you have access

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I'm trying to spin up a new stack via a lambda function, like so:

```
var cloudformation = new AWS.CloudFormation();

cloudformation.createStack({
    StackName: 'example',
    TemplateURL: 'https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/my.s3bucket/cloudformationtemplate.yml',
    Capabilities: ['CAPABILITY_IAM', 'CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM'],
    RoleARN: 'arn:aws:iam::1234567890AB:role/myRole'
})
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

> TemplateURL must reference a valid S3 object to which you have access

So far I've tried adding...

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::my.s3bucket"
    ]
}
```

...to myRole (passed in as the RoleARN param on createStack()), and also to the IAM execution role linked to the lambda itself.

However, no luck.

Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add `ListBucket` permission as well.

Ex:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME"]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a go.  Should that be against the lambda Role or the RoleARN role.  I'll try both.

Comment: As per your scenario, this should be in 'myRole'

Comment: @Luke Glad I could help :)